# Explain the working of var img = new Image();

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, dom-events

When working with HTML5 canvas I came across some code like this:

```
var img = new Image();   // Create new img element

 img.addEventListener("load", function() {}, false);

img.src = 'myImage.png'; // Set source path
```

The way I understand it is that the event gets executed on the last line, when `img.src` is set.

So how does the `load` event fire when it is not called?

Consider this:

```
var psudpImage=function(){
var psudoSrc;
}

var img = new psudpImage();
img.psudosrc="'myImage.png'";
```

I know I am missing something here, that's why I am asking.

In my example the psudosrc doesn't interfere with other elements of the function, so why is it that happens in the `Image()` function?

Comment: I suggest that you give a good read about `events` before even starting to work with web development.

Comment: *"So how does the load event fire when it is not called?*" Um the browser fires the load event after the image is fetched. Do you know how window.onload works? Same idea.

Answer (score 4):

The browser itself calls the event handler internally. Have you ever used an `onclick` event? You don't manually call that either - when you click, the browser calls the function. Same here - when the image is loaded, the browser calls the handler.